# How to display user names on Confluence

Tags: confluence

Our team is using Confluence to track the user status every week, so we have the host name of each week.

How can I display the current week's host and next week host by looping the user name list in confluence? The host is one of the user name from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@` to address any colleague, for example, `@ZhianABCD`, assuming the employee is active in the company directories, such as active directory!

For more shortcuts, follow these guidelines

*[A quick and easy guide to Confluence shortcuts](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/confluence/keyboard-shortcuts-guide)*

Comment: thanks for your comments, let me make it more clear, the request could be like this
Suppose that we have a list of user names like zhianABCD, zhianBCDE, zhianCDEF,

The current week, I want to show two labels zhianABCD and zhianBCDE
The next week, I want to show two labels zhianBCDE and zhianCDEF
Then third week, I want to show two labels zhianCDEF and zhianABCD

Comment: If you want it dynamically, you may code a `Macro` , see here https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/macros-139387.html , not sure which would be more suitable but `code block` macro might help ! If you know, just by MS excel or so, macros are small self executing scripts :)

Comment: Re *"active directory"*: As a common noun? Or *[Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)* (Microsoft's directory service)?

Comment: `Active directory` (Microsoft's directory service) !